# Uploading blank file when FTP path has more than one subdirectory

Tags: java, file-upload, ftp, ftp-client

Below code uploads file on the FTP server

```
public class UploadFile {
    static ResourceBundle rsBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.mindcraft.resources.resources");
    public void upload(String host,String username,String pwd,String inputfile,String uploadpath,String zip_filename)
    {      
        //String zip_file_name= rsBundle.getString("zip_filename");
        FTPClient ftp=new FTPClient();
        try {          
            int reply;  
            ftp.connect(host); 
            ftp.login(username, pwd); 
            reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
            System.out.println("reply1" + reply);
            if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) 
            {             
                ftp.disconnect();           

            }           
            System.out.println("FTP server connected."); 
            ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            InputStream input= new FileInputStream(inputfile);

            System.out.println("Directory.." + ftp.printWorkingDirectory());

            String dirTree=uploadpath;
            boolean dirExists = true;
            String[] directories = dirTree.split("/");
            for (String dir : directories )
            {
                if (!dir.isEmpty() )
                {
                    if (dirExists)
                    {
                        dirExists = ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);
                        ftp.storeFile(dirTree+zip_filename,input);
                        System.out.println("1..");
                    }
                    if (!dirExists)
                    {

                        System.out.println("dir tree" + ftp.printWorkingDirectory());


                        if (!ftp.makeDirectory(dir))
                        {

                            throw new IOException("Unable to create remote directory '" + dir + "'.  error='" + ftp.getReplyString()+"'");
                            }
                        if (!ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(dir))
                        {

                            throw new IOException("Unable to change into newly created remote directory '" + dir + "'.  error='" + ftp.getReplyString()+"'");
                        }
                        System.out.println("dir tree" + ftp.printWorkingDirectory());
                        ftp.storeFile(dirTree+zip_filename,input);
                    }

                    }
                }      

            System.out.println( ftp.getReplyString() );
            input.close();
            ftp.logout();        
            } 
        catch(Exception e) 
            {                      
            System.out.println("err"+ e);          
            e.printStackTrace();     
            }
        finally 
        {
            if(ftp.isConnected())
            {
                try
                { 
                    ftp.disconnect();

                }
                catch(Exception ioe)
                {

                }

            }

        }
        } 
}
```

It works fine when the upload path has one folder eg. `/folder1/`

But It uploads blank file of byte 0 when there is subfolder or more than one directory eg. `/folder1/folder2/`

What can be the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ftp.storeFile(dirTree+zip_filename,input);` should be called after the `for` creating all subdirectories, and going to the correct directory.

BTW could have helped introducing a function makeAndGoToDirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Joop Eggen got the point, I would just like to add that if you want to retrieve files/directories, it is a good practice to write:

`String[] directories = dirTree.split(File.separator);`

instead of

`String[] directories = dirTree.split("/");`

because it will make your code more portable. FTP server doesn't always need to stay on Unix/Linux.